# How to set image from API to Carousel in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, carousel

I want to use a Banner Slider in Flutter apps, so I found a library to make it, namely `Carousel`. This is a good library but I found a problem for this library, `How to set image from API into Carousel?` or `have any library for support image from API (list), have dot indicator, autoplay like Carousel?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Carousel package -: carousel_slider: ^1.3.0

```
    CarouselSlider(
          autoPlay: true,
          pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 5),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.60,
          items: <Widget>[
            for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(image[i]),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                    // border:
                    //     Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                  ),
                ),                                     
          ],
        ),
```